# Find the latest version of sdk-tools-linux-*.zip

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I use Travis to run my JUnit tests on Android via the emulator. This works very well so far. However, how can I determine what the latest version of sdk-tools-linux-*.zip is? Currently, I am using version 4333796. Are there any dependencies between the SDK tools version and the Android SDK version or the build tools version?

```
- name: Tests on Android
  jdk: openjdk8
  env:
    - ANDROID_TOOLS=4333796
    - ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=29
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=29.0.3
    - ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android-sdk
    - PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
  before_install:
    - sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends bridge-utils libpulse0 libvirt-bin qemu-kvm virtinst ubuntu-vm-builder > /dev/null
    - sudo apt-get install -y libxtst6 libnss3-dev libnspr4 libxss1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 > /dev/null
    - sudo adduser $USER libvirt
    - sudo adduser $USER kvm
    - wget -q "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_TOOLS}.zip" -O android-sdk-tools.zip
    - unzip -q android-sdk-tools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME}
    - rm android-sdk-tools.zip
    - wget -q "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmcc007/test_emulators/master/script/android-wait-for-emulator.sh" -O android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator gradlew
    - touch $HOME/.android/repositories.cfg
    - yes | sdkmanager --licenses > /dev/null
  install:
    - sdkmanager "platform-tools" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "tools" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION}" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "system-images;android-${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION};default;x86" > /dev/null
    - sdkmanager "emulator" > /dev/null
    - echo no | avdmanager create avd --force -n test -k "system-images;android-${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION};default;x86"
  before_script:
    - sudo -E sudo -u $USER -E bash -c "${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator -avd test -no-window -no-audio &"
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
  script:
    - TERM=dumb ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy!

The latest version will always be 4333796 because sdk-tools is deprecated. If you want to use the new approach, use commandlinetools-linux instead :)

Comment: Good to know :D I will try to switch to command line tools. As I read, these tools come already bundled with the Android SDK. So, I could probably even simplify my script :)

Comment: Yes, they are included by default. Other non-essential packages like emulator images, SDKs, etc don't. However, everything's quite easy to install with sdk-manager.

Comment: How to get the proper repository details ? i need latest version to upgrade my sdk version to 31.

Answer (score 3):

To find the new version (it's now `commandlinetools-linux` instead of `sdk-tools`) come here:

https://developer.android.com/studio

And at the end look at `Command line tools only`

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer `sdk-tools`. It is now `commandlinetools-linux`

Use below url to setup your Ci/CD

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip